# Question about the degree of differential equation

Tags: calculus

[image]

Is that the correct answer in the picture? According to the definition, The degree of a differential equation is the power of the highest order derivative in the equation, so my question is why the result is not 1 (because the first term is the highest order derivative) but 3?

Answer (score 2):

If we accept the widely used definitions:

- **Order**: The order of a differential equation is the highest derivative that appears in the differential equation.
- **Degree**: The degree of a differential equation is the power of the highest derivative term.

This is a second order, first degree differential equation. I found the picture of [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Differential-Equations) and I guess the picture tries to say degree of equation in terms of x is three.